# Displaying only png and jpeg files

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Im Currently working in a GUI project. When i run the code , the explorer opens and all types of files i.e png , pdf, jpeg , zip files .
But i want only jpeg and png files to display

```
import customtkinter as ctk 
from imageWidgets import * 
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from menu import Menu

class App(ctk.CTk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._set_appearance_mode('dark')
    self.geometry('1000x600')
    self.title('Image Editor')
    self.minsize(800, 400)
    
    # geometry 
    self.rowconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
    self.columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 2, uniform = 'b')
    self.columnconfigure(index = 1, weight = 6, uniform = 'b')

    # widgets
    self.imageImport = ImageImport(self, self.importImage)
    self.imageImport.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'nsew')

    # run
    self.mainloop()    
    
  def importImage(self, path):
    self.image = Image.open(path)
    self.imageRatio = self.image.size[0] / self.image.size[1] # Returns Tuple
    
    self.imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
    
    self.imageImport.grid_forget()
    self.imageOutput = ImageOutput(self, self.resizeImage)
    self.closeBtn = CloseOutput(self, command = self.closeEdit)
    
    self.menu = Menu(self)
    
  def resizeImage(self, event):
    
    # current canvas ratio
    canvasRatio = event.width / event.height
        
    # resize
    if (canvasRatio > self.imageRatio): # Canvas wider than image
      imageHeight = int(event.height)
      imageWidth = int(imageHeight * self.imageRatio)
    else: # canvas taller than image
      imageWidth = int(event.width)
      imageHeight = int(imageWidth / self.imageRatio)
      
    
    self.imageOutput.delete('all')
    resizedImage = self.image.resize((imageWidth, imageHeight))
    self.imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizedImage)
    self.imageOutput.create_image(event.width/2, event.height/2, image = self.imageTk)

  def closeEdit(self):
    self.imageOutput.grid_forget()
    self.closeBtn.place_forget()
    self.menu.grid_forget()
    self.imageImport = ImageImport(self, self.importImage)
    self.imageImport.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'nsew')

app = App()
```

Here is the code . When runned a dialog box opens with a button 'open image'. When clicked it opens file explorer . There it displays all types of file. I want only png and jpeg files .
Here is the code for ***menu.py and imageWidgets.py***
**menu.py:**
import customtkinter as ctk

```
class Menu(ctk.CTkTabview):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(master = parent)
    self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
    
    # tabs
    self.add('Position')
    self.add('Color')
    self.add('Effects')
    self.add('Export')
    
    # widgets
    PositionFrame(self.tab('Position'))
    ColorFrame(self.tab('Color'))

class PositionFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(master = parent, fg_color = 'transparent')
    self.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

class ColorFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(master = parent, fg_color = 'transparent')
    self.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

**imageWidgets.py:**
import customtkinter as ctk 
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import Canvas
from settings import *

class ImageImport(ctk.CTkFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent, importFunc):
    super().__init__(master = parent)
    self.importFunc = importFunc
    
    # widget
    self.button = ctk.CTkButton(master = self, text = 'Open Image', command = self.openDiag)
    self.button.pack(expand = True)

  def openDiag(self):
    path = fd.askopenfile().name # type:ignore
    self.importFunc(path)
    
class ImageOutput(ctk.CTkCanvas):
  def __init__(self, parent, resizeImage):
    super().__init__(
      master = parent, 
      background = BACKGROUND, 
      bd = 0, 
      highlightthickness = 0, 
      relief = 'ridge'
      )
    self.bind('<Configure>', resizeImage)
    self.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew')
    
class CloseOutput(ctk.CTkButton):
  def __init__(self, parent, command):
    super().__init__(
      master = parent, 
      text = 'X', 
      text_color = WHITE, 
      fg_color = 'transparent',
      width = 40, 
      height = 40, # make it as square
      corner_radius = 0, 
      hover_color = CLOSE_RED, 
      command = command
     )
    self.place(relx = 0.99, rely = 0.01, anchor = 'ne')
```

And there is another file **setting.py** imported in the **imageWidgets.py**
Here is the code for **settings.py**:

```
# default values
ROTATE_DEFAULT = 0
ZOOM_DEFAULT = 0
FLIP_OPTIONS = ['None', 'X', 'Y', 'Both']
BLUR_DEFAULT = 0
CONTRAST_DEFAULT = 0
EFFECT_DEFAULT = ['None', 'Emboss', 'Find Edges', 'Contour', 'Edge Enhance']
BRIGHTNESS_DEFAULT = 1
VIBRANCE_DEFAULT = 1
GRAYSCALE_DEFAULT = False
INVERT_DEFAULT = False

# COLORS 
WHITE = '#FFF'
GREY = 'grey'
BLUE = '#1f6aa5'
DARK_GREY = '#4a4a4a'
CLOSE_RED = '#8a0606'
BACKGROUND = '#242424'

SLIDER_BG = '#64686b'
```

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the file dialog to only support specific file types? That's a documented feature. Why do you need our help?

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid them:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 0):

File dialog of `tkinter` have several options, compare the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html):

Example:

```
file = askopenfile(title='Please select image.', filetypes=[('Image Files', ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png'])])
```